# KDE global shortcuts stopped working. KDED trouble?

Tags: linux, kde

I'm running the latest KDE4 and have gotten used to my Yakuake dropdown console.

The problem is that the global shortcuts in KDE stopped working, which basically makes my whole environment unusable now.

How can I fix this?

I restarted kded as suggested in some forums, but to no avail.

Thanks in advance, I'd love to understand the mechanisms for this better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe KWin provides the global shortcuts you're missing.  Generally, you'll also see the loss of the decorations on any windows, along with a missing 'main bar' (?? taskbar?)

yakuake is wonderful!

A question would be: which shortcuts are you missing?  The general 'everyone has' shortcuts are usually from KWin, while those you've set up yourself are served through khotkeys.

I base this on the listing of hotkeys found in the "Keyboard & Mouse" panel in System Settings.  Choose the Global Keyboard Shortcuts (bottom left) and then choose things in the dropdown on top-right.  KWin handles ALT-F4, ALT-TAB, stuff like that, while khotkeys handles those I've added myself (WIN-S=shell, WIN-C=calc, WIN-V=gvim, etc)

Comment: i've tried to kill kglobalaccel, and run it again, but the global shortcut still stopped working..