# KDE global hotkeys not working any more

Tags: kde, freebsd

Since I installed to KDE 4.4.x I lost any "global accelerator" facility, including Alt-Tab, Alt-F1 and Ctrl-F1-F4 which of course renders the whole experience a lot… slower.

Upgrading later to KDE 4.5.5 didn't help either.

I'm running FreeBSD 8.1/amd64 and, as far as I can see, kglobalaccel is working:

```
% qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kwin org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.isActive
true
```

Any idea what else I could check to debug the issue?

Comment: Whoops, I only noticed a duplicate after posting this question, but that doesn't have a solution either: http://superuser.com/questions/195777/

Comment: Let's see if any KDE guru can help… http://lists.kde.org/?l=kde&m=129536323529688&w=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit by bisection on configuration files under `~/.kde4/share/config` (removing half of them, then one quarter…) and the culprit was an old patch I forgot to have applied.

Comment: What was the patch?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but it was related to supporting the media keys on my Apple Aluminium USB keyboard (and no, it didn't work, because with the current FreeBSD driver the extra key don't even generate a low-level event).

Comment: Hm. That's odd, but I guess I'd need to try this approach as well - it just happened on it's own after some upgrade